# Letting compiler write operator==, <, > etc. via spaceship-operator

Tags: c++, comparison, std-variant, spaceship-operator

I'm trying my luck with the spaceship operator. Say I have a variant-like object (that I conveninently derive from `std::variant` with fixed template parameters) and I want to define operators ==, <, >, !=, etc... for easy comparison, I thought I could just spaceship-it according to the contained type and have the compiler define all operators by itself:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:25,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:25,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:25,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:25),source:%27%23include+%3Ccompare%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aclass+JSON+:+public+std::variant%3Cstd::monostate,+double,+std::string%3E+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++using+variant::variant%3B%0A%0A++++auto+operator%3C%3D%3E(std::string+str)+const+%7B%0A++++++++return+std::get%3Cstd::string%3E(*this)+%3C%3D%3E+str%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++auto+operator%3C%3D%3E(double+d)+const+%7B%0A++++++++return+std::get%3Cdouble%3E(*this)+%3C%3D%3E+d%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A++%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++JSON+myjson+%3D+2.3%3B%0A%0A++++if+(myjson+%3D%3D+2.3)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22JSON+was+2.3%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

class JSON : public std::variant<std::monostate, double, std::string> {
public:
    using variant::variant;

    auto operator<=>(std::string str) const {
        return std::get<std::string>(*this) <=> str;
    }
    auto operator<=>(double d) const {
        return std::get<double>(*this) <=> d;
    }
};
  
int main()
{
    JSON myjson = 2.3;

    if (myjson == 2.3) {
        std::cout << "JSON was 2.3" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Yet this apporach yields:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:22:16: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'JSON' and 'double')
   22 |     if (myjson == 2.3) {
      |         ~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
      |         |         |
      |         JSON      double
```

I would have thought that the compiler now knows how to write `operator==` for my variant object in case rhs is a double or rhs is a string. In case the variant contains a different alternative, I'm fine with std::get throwing at me.

Comment: `operator==` is *only* synthesized if `operator<=>` is declared as `default`, which is not your case, so `operator==` still needs to be provided for your class.

Comment: I think only providing `auto operator<=>(const JSON& d) const = default` in your example will do the trick.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Indeed it does! What is happening? I guess the compiler uses std::variant(double) to implicitely convert the double to a JSON and then uses the inbuilt operator== to compare two JSON objects?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Reflecting upon it again it sems the same could be achieved by pulling in base class operator<=>, no? However, this doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/q1b8Y6shj

Comment: The reason `auto operator<=>(const JSON& d) const = default `works is that `double` is converted to `JSON`, so comparing two `JSON`s will invoke the `variant`'s comparison function. The example you provided does not work because you are comparing `double` with `JSON`, which does not match the `variant` comparison function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Default comparisons (since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons):

> Per the rules for any operator<=> overload, a defaulted <=> overload > will also allow the type to be compared with <, <=, >, and >=.

> If operator<=> is defaulted and operator== is not declared at all,
> then operator== is implicitly defaulted.

As you can see in the link above, this is the only mention of an implicit default `operator==` based on `operator<=>`.

In your case `operator<=>` is not `default`ed, and so the above does not apply.
Therefore you need to supply `operator==` (or in the general case have it itself `default`ed if possible based on the operand types).

**Note:**

As [@康桓瑋 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77086360/letting-compiler-write-operator-etc-via-spaceship-operator/77086414#comment135894948_77086360), in your specific case you could actually `default`ed `operator<=>`:

```
auto operator<=>(const JSON& d) const = default;
```

As explained above, it works because `double` is converted to `JSON`, so comparing two `JSON`s will invoke the `variant`'s comparison method.

Comment: Can you add how to solve it (see @康桓瑋's comment on OP)?

Comment: Defaulting `==` doesn't implement it in terms of `<=>`, but rather by directly comparing the fields, isn't it? I don't think you can default it if the operand types don't match.

Comment: @glades added an update.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think you are correct. Added a clarification.